# docker smack security on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, docker, access-control

I'm trying to run a docker container for a [smack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smack_(software))-based application. So, have added `security=smack` to the ubuntu host grub, and rebooted.

Now on the ubuntu host, the smack works by running these two commands:

```
mkdir smackdir
mount -t smackfs smack smackdir
```

The goal is to be able to run the smackfs mount command in a container.

However, all the docker containers are in stopped state, and the command `docker start ...` just hangs. Creating a new container does not work either, it simply hangs.

[The docker run-command-reference page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) mentions two options `--cap-add MAC_OVERRIDE` and `--cap-add MAC_ADMIN`. It mentions `the Smack LSM` too so clearly the design is there. Tried the options with docker run or docker start commands, no success. How to get it work?

The ubuntu version is 16.04.1 LTS, and docker 1.10.3 from ubuntu.

---

**Detailed steps:**

Pulled ubuntu image, and it ran ok with default kernel security:

```
$ docker pull ubuntu
$ docker run -it -d --privileged ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Modify `/etc/default/grub` so it looks like the following and run `update-grub` to update the grub menu. Then reboot.

```
# grep GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT /etc/default/grub
###GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="security=smack"

# update-grub
```

After reboot, mount smackfs on the ubuntu host, it works ok.

```
# mkdir smk
# mount -t smackfs smack smk
```

The docker commands below work well. It shows container `cranky_roentgen` was stopped:

```
$ docker images
$ docker ps -a
```

Start the container, it hangs forever:

```
$ docker start cranky_roentgen
```

The command with `--privileged` hangs forever too:

```
$ docker run -it -d --privileged ubuntu /bin/bash
```

The command to use `--cap-add` hangs forever too:

```
$ docker run -it -d --cap-add=MAC_OVERRIDE --cap-add=MAC_ADMIN ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Using `strace`, it stops at a call to `futex()`:

```
$ strace docker run -it -d --cap-add=MAC_OVERRIDE --cap-add=MAC_ADMIN ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Here the last few lines of `strace` of the above that shows the futex without a closing parentheses:

```
mmap(0xc81ffe0000, 32768, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xc81ffe0000
stat("/home/dkr/.docker/config.json", 0xc8203385e8) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
futex(0x12fe988, FUTEX_WAIT, 0, NULL
^Cstrace: Process 1603 detached
 <detached ...>
```

Comment: Please include details about the commands you are running and the image you are using.

Comment: updated with detailed steps of commands